A question about meditation practice
Во время медитации очень сильное ощущение в макушке головы. Если направляю внимание на дыхание то ощущение усиливается, распространяется по всему мозгу, Ощущается именно внутри головы , наблюдаю дальше, направляю внимание на дыхание через это место с ощущением в макушке головы вниз по позвоночнику, это ощущение становится еще и пульсирующим как сердце и спускается вниз по
During meditation there is a very strong sensation at the top of the head. If I direct my attention to my breathing, the sensation intensifies, spreads throughout the brain, I feel it inside my head, I observe further, I direct my attention to my breathing through this place with a feeling at the top of my head down the spine, this feeling also becomes pulsating like a heart and goes down the spine.
позвончнику до ануса, иногда пульсирует и вызывает приятные ощущения, иногда сильно жгет как будто что-то горит неприятно (однажды даже выскочил Геморой но не реагировал на него просто наблюдал и он через неделю исчез), дышу и провожу внимание дальше перемещается ощущение в промежности. Наблюдаю дальше, дышу спокойно, ровно, наблюдаю дальше
the spine to the anus, sometimes it pulsates and causes pleasant sensations, sometimes it burns strongly as if something was burning unpleasantly (once a Hemorrhoid even popped up but did not react to it, I just observed it and after a week it disappeared), I breathe and pay attention, then the sensation moves in the perineum. I continue to observe, I breathe calmly, evenly, I continue to observe the sensations in the perineum, the sensation
за ощущениями в промежности, ощущение усиливается ( однажды так пульсировало что произошла эрекция, неожидал такого самопроизвольного действия от тело так как практиковал долгое время воздержание), перемещается в гениталии, тоже там усиливается, поднимается в низ живота и также усиливается иногда приятные сильные сексуальные ощущения иногда сильно жгет как будто горит, наблюдаю дальше,
behind the sensations in the perineum, the sensation intensifies (once it throbbed so much that an erection occurred, I did not expect such a spontaneous action from the body since I had been practicing abstinence for a long time), moves to the genitals, also intensifies there, rises to the lower abdomen and sometimes pleasant strong sexual sensations also intensify it burns strongly, as if it’s on fire, I keep watching,
поднимется в пупок и также останавливаться усиливается, перемещается выше в солнечное спляетине и так далее, в груди в горло и в области между глаз конечная станция и начинается новый круг. Все ли Иде как надо? На что нужно обращать внимания? Иногда с макушки поток не идет в низ по позвоночнику а как будто что сильно тянет вверху или как будто меня из тело вытягивает. Возникает переживание, наблюдаю за этим,
rises to the navel and also stops, intensifies, moves higher into the solar patch and so on, in the chest to the throat and in the area between the eyes the final station and a new circle begins. Is everything as it should be for Ida? What should you pay attention to? Sometimes from the top of my head the flow does not go down the spine, but as if something is strongly pulling at the top or as if I am being pulled out of my body. An experience arises, I observe it,
вытягивание останавливается и направляется за вниманием вниз по позвоночнику. После, подумал, может не стоит сопротивляться, будет что будет, тянет вверх и тянет ну и что , просто наблюдать что дальше. Понял что при появление ощущения в макушке, если направляю
the stretching stops and is directed down the spine for attention. Afterwards, I thought, maybe it’s not worth resisting, whatever will happen, it pulls up and pulls, so what, just watch what happens next. I realized that when a sensation appears in the top of the head, if I direct
внимание на пространство над головой, то начинает вытягивать снова вверх. Что это происходит, это нормально или нет? Присутствует немного паники по этому поводу. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, правильно ли все идет в моей практики медитации?
attention to the space above your head, then begins to pull up again. What is this happening, is it normal or not? There is a bit of panic about this. Please help me figure out if everything is going right in my meditation practice?

Buddhist meditation is training in letting go of attachment and training in detached observation.
Буддийская медитация – это тренировка отпускания привязанностей и тренировка беспристрастного наблюдения.
Buddhist meditation is not chasing after and reacting towards every physical neurological and respiratory nuance.
Буддийская медитация не гонится за каждым физическим, неврологическим и респираторным нюансом и не реагирует на него.
Your observing mind should remain equanimous and should not get caught up and obsessed with physical neurological and respiratory phenomena.
Ваш наблюдающий ум должен оставаться невозмутимым и не должен быть захвачен и одержим физическими неврологическими и респираторными явлениями

It's all normal, don't worry about it.
I've written some articles on the topic here:
https://notesonthedhamma.blogspot.com/2020/02/meditation-q.html
The general principle is, if you stay celibate, charge up your jhāna battery, the body is going to generate strong forces that try to harmonize the 4 elements in the body. It will get healthier, stronger, your mind will get clearer and sharper. That is, if you stay celibate and keep meditating. If you don't, then you can be a normal human with the normal problems they have.
